# Binding dropdown in angularjs via api and exporting same in excel sheet

Tags: html, angularjs, excel, alasql

following is the plunker link
[plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/00nfeq12/)

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>
    <br />
    <div id="exportable">
      <label class="control-label">Color</label>
      <select name="color" ng-model="inv.ColorId" id="color" required class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select the Color">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select the color
        </option>
        <option value={{color.Id}} ng-repeat="color in ColorList | orderBy:'ColorName'">
          {{color.ColorName}}
        </option>
      </select>
      <table width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            <td>{{item.dob | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i hv binded the working api to bind values to dropdown however not getting the dropdown in exported excel sheet . Any help with this ?

Comment: what you exactly want? excel sheet with drop down? In plunker, there is no drop down code?

Comment: yes, dropdown values prepopulated with api obtained values

Comment: what you do with that color? does that should come up as a column or color will be applied to excel sheet or what?

Comment: yes..it should appear as dropdown in exported excel sheet

Comment: I have added `$scope.ColorList = [{
      colorName: 'red',
     }, {colorName: 'green'}, {colorName: 'blue'}];`  now what ?

Comment: i need dropdown with those values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147598/discussion-between-sanjanahe-and-pro-mean).